# What is an exponential singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms

In Ken Ono's Lecture notes on Harmonic Maass forms and Mock Modular Functions ([here](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2013/2013OnoNotes.pdf)) the author uses the term "exponential singularity". What does this mean?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: consider that it is an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) equivalent to the singularity of $h(z) = e^{1/z}$ at $z=0$

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent to the singularity"? Is there some kind of an equivalence relation or do you mean that they are both essential?